# Packed bubble adding image for bubble background

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, bubble-chart, graphical-logo, packed

is it possible to have images in bubbles for backgrounds in packed bubble highcharts?

I looked around but wasnt able to find such an option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can achieve this by setting `packedbubble.marker.symbol` per series or directly per point.

```
series: [{
    marker: {
        symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/earth.svg)'
    },
data: [{
  value: 67.1,
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9a/Trollface_non-free.png/220px-Trollface_non-free.png)'
        },
}, {
  value: 520.7
}]
```

}]

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mb7fr95z/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.packedbubble.marker.symbol